# Present perfect common problem

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

I have bought this jacket earlier. 
This is wrong because the action of buying a jacket is already finished.

However, you can say I have had this jacket for 4 years (present perfect here indicates that you still have the jacket.)

**Did I get this right?**

Comment: Costa, do you speak Spanish or Portuguese? I have bought books recently. That indicates past but not **exactly when**: I bought this book yesterday. You could also have: I had this jacket for four years, if you no longer have it.

Comment: Almost. It's not actually *wrong* to use Present Perfect in your first example - just "not common". And for the second example, it's really just the word ***this*** that pretty much forces the Perfect form - if we just change it to ***that** jacket*, it becomes perfectly credible to suppose that the jacket has just been stolen, sold, destroyed, or whatever (I no longer "have" it; perhaps no-one else does either). All the Perfect really indicates is *strong relevance to time of utterance*. It doesn't *always* have to imply "still continuing action".

Comment: ...in fact, if the speaker has just ***sold*** "this jacket" to whoever he's talking to, it could be perfectly natural to use Present Perfect even if he's just handed "this jacket" over, so he definitely no longer has it.